# Multiple App delegates with storyboard

Tags: appdelegate

Hello there everyone,

I am new to IOS development and currently I am trying to understand app delegates and how they work.

I know the fact once the project is created by default an app delegate.h/m is generated.
However, I am using my current AppDelegate for setting core data, and I need to work on Facebook integration as well in my storyboard, looking at the code, I can not use one method to recall tasks, am I right? .

Do I use both the Facebook integration and core in the same AppDelegate file?
Or do I create new AppDelegate file and make the Facebook integration?
And if yes, how do I create new AppDelegate?

Any links for tutorials?
Because I do not know if I can use two different view controllers for the same method:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Note that I am using sotryboard no XIB

Answer (score 1):

Try these sites; I cannot guarantee you will immediately find what your looking for, but as a fellow person working his way through app development, I'm sure you know how important it is to patiently and thoroughly analyze any helpful material.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AppArchitecture/AppArchitecture.html

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-6/